# order of a rational function

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a variety, i.e. integral scheme, finite type over a field. Now for a rational function $r$ we can define the order along a codimension 1 subvariety $V$ via

${ord}_V(r)=l_A(A/ (r)A)$, where $A$ denotes the local ring of the subvarietey. Now I want to show that for a given rational function, there are only finitely many codimension one subvarieties, such that the order is non-zero.

For this I want to show that the union of such codimension one subvarieties is a closed subset. Note that the order is 0, iff $r$ is a unit in $\mathcal O_{V,X}$. This also implies that if $r\not \in \mathcal O_{V,W}$, then for any $x\in V$ also $r\not \in \mathcal O_{X,x}$.  Now if $x\in X$ such that $r\in \mathcal O_{X,x}$, we can find some open subset of $X$ where this is still true.

But how do I handle the case for an $x\in X, \ r\in \mathcal O_{X,x}^*$ such that there exists no codim. 1 subvariety $V$ with $r\in \mathcal O_{V,X}$? I think I need to do something with Krull's principal ideal theorem but I am struggling with how to apply it.

Sincerely, slin

Comment: Please ignore my comment if it's irrelevant, but why not use the same proof as Hartshorne ? The locus where $r$ has a pole or a pole is closed, and is a proper closed subset of $X$ if $r$ is not-constant. So it can contains only finitely many prime divisors and you are done.

Comment: where do I find this in Hartshorne? I tried looking for it but couldn't find it

Comment: It's page 131 of my edition (II.6, Lemma 6.1 )

Comment: this only solves indeed the regular case. Now I could use that the smooth locus is open which would complete the proof of the statement above with a simple argument.